# License needed to use a custom web font

Tags: legal, fonts

I want to use a custom font on my website.
I have found the woff file of this font on another website who was using it.
I've saved it on my computer, tested it on my website (localhost only) and it works.
However, after some research, I found that multiple website are selling this font.

So I'm wondering, can I use the woff file on my website just like this (probably not)? If I simply buy the font, is it enough to use it on my website or should I obtain some kind of special license to do so ?

I don't intend to sell the font so I'm not sure it is relevant but I'm talking about a commercial website. I don't know if it can be considered as a commercial use or not.

Lastly, the web-font I'm talking about is sold on the following website:

- http://www.fonts.com/
- https://www.myfonts.com/

Comment: *If something is* ***SOLD*** *why would you think you could use it for* ***FREE?***

Comment: @SimonHayter  That's why I said "probably not", but as a counter example teamviewer, as many software, can be used freely for a personal use and you should buy a license for professional use. It's free, but it's also sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can not use a font you stole off a web site that the creator charges for and licenses. For the type foundry to sell a license, but not the font, would be bizarre at best. Just buy the font and be legal.